# Armstrong Number Print Error

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a function in C++ that recognizes and prints Armstrong numbers in a range from one to where specified by a user. It also returns how many there are as an integer. The largest number it will read to is 9,999.

The issue I have is that it recognizes every Armstrong number up to 8208, but not 9474, which are both Armstrong numbers. This brings me great confusion as I process numbers based on the amount of digits they have, so if it successfully identifies 8208, it should also identify 9474. It does not.

Here is my code:

```
int isArmstrongNum(int range){
    int count = 0;
    int ones;
    int tens;
    int hundreds;
    int thousands;
    if(range < 1 || range > 9999){
        cout << "invalid entry" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < range; i++){
        if(i < 10){
            if(pow(i, 1) == i){
                count++;
                cout << i << endl;
            }
        }
        else if(i > 9 && i < 100){
            ones = i % 10;
            tens = (i - ones) / 10;
            if(pow(ones,2) + pow(tens,2) == i){
                count++;
                cout << i << endl;
            }
        }
        else if(i > 99 && i < 1000){
            ones = i % 10;
            tens = ((i % 100) - ones) / 10;
            hundreds = (i - tens * 10 - ones) / 100;
            if(pow(ones,3) + pow(tens, 3) + pow(hundreds,3) == i){
                count++;
                cout << i << endl;
            }
        }
        else if(i > 999 && i < 10000){
            ones = i % 10;
            tens = ((i % 100) - ones) / 10;
            hundreds = ((i % 1000) - tens*10 - ones) / 100;
            thousands = (i - hundreds * 100 - tens * 10 - ones) / 1000;
            if(pow(ones,4) + pow(tens, 4) + pow(hundreds, 4) + 
pow(thousands, 4) == i){
                count++;
                cout << i << endl;
            }
        }

    }
    return count;
```

}

Any idea why it behaves this way? Thanks.

Comment: if you were asked to find Amstrong Number till 1000000 will you still create those many variable and conditional statements? I suggest you should first generalize your program.

Comment: Don't use `pow` to square an integer - use `x * x`. Similarly for the other small integer powers.

Comment: You should rename the function since it's kind of misleading...

Comment: What's the deal with `pow(i,1)`?  Is it necessary (think about the math of raising a number to the first power)?

Comment: The [`pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) function returns floating point.  Also `x * x` is more efficient than `pow(x, 2)`.

Comment: The code for this program is for an assignment in my college class. While my code looks inefficient in more ways the one, I do this to strictly adhere to the calculation example shown in its introduction so I do not lose points.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps!

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

bool is_armstrong(int number)
{
    int length=0,n=number,temp=0;
    while(n>0)
    {
        length++;
        n/=10;
    }
    n=number;
    while(n>0)
    {
        temp+=pow(n%10,length);
        n/=10;
    }
    if(temp==number)
        return true;
    return false;
}

int main() 
{
    int i,start_range=1,end_range=9999;
    for(i=start_range;i<=end_range;i++)
    {
        if(is_armstrong(i))
            cout<<i<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

Output:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
153
370
371
407
1634
8208
9474
```

Comment: Please explain *why* this code would help?  Why is it different?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Since you don't have to create a conditional statement for each digit like hundred or thousand.

Comment: When you post code as an answer, please annotate your code and answer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I guess it's fairly understandable by any c++ programmer but still, I will.